# Expression<Func<TModel, string>> where TModel is an interface, type is never the passed implemenation

Tags: c#, generics, asp.net-mvc-5, html-helper

I created a custom HtmlHelper to render an address on a webpage. The address needs to be dynamic based on the country the address is in. For this I have a simple interface with multiple implementations. My controller passes the specific implementation to the view which is strongly typed to the interface. When debugging, the view shows the correct implementing type and I pass that model to my custom HtmlHelper as a generic type parameter. This custom HtmlHelper only accepts models of type IAddress or its implementation, but the TModel is always IAddress no matter what type is passed into it. This is an issue due to the attributes on the individual implementations as I use the existing HtmlHelpers such as Html.EditorFor and Html.LabelFor within my own helper to render the fields and labels for the address including proper validation when submitted.

I believe the issues is that the View is strongly typed to IAddress and the HtmlHelper ignores the actual model type and goes straight for the view type, how can I get around this?

Interface and Implementing Classes:

```
public interface IAddress
{
    // Dumbed down to one property to save space
    String City { get; set; }
    String State { get; set; }
}

public class AddressUS : IAddress
{
    // Required and displayed on page.
    [DisplayName("City")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "City is required!")]
    public String City { get; set; }

    // Required and displayed on page.
    [DisplayName("State")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "State is required!")]
    public String State { get; set; }
}

public class AddressJP : IAddress
{
    // Required and displayed on page.
    [DisplayName("Prefecture")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Prefecture is required!")]
    public String City { get; set; }

    // Not required and not displayed on page.
    [DisplayName("State")]
    public String State { get; set; }
}
```

Controller Action:

```
public ActionResult DisplayAddress()
{
    // Returning a specific type for testing.
    AddressJP address = new AddressJP() { City = "Test" };
}
```

View:

```
@* 
    Set to the interface to accept all implementations, but possibly also the cause of the issue.
    Setting to AddressJP, but I need it dynamic.
*@
@model IAddress
@using Custom.HtmlExtensions

<div id="address">
    @Html.AddressEditorForModel(true)
</div>
```

HtmlHelper:

```
public static MvcHtmlString AddressEditorForModel<TModel>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, Boolean showLabels) where TModel : IAddress
    {
        // TModel is always IAddress unless I change the view to be a specific implementation.

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        PropertyInfo pInfo = typeof(TModel).GetProperty("City");
        ParameterExpression paramExpr = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TModel));
        MemberExpression propertyAccess = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(paramExpr, pInfo);
        var lambdaExpr = Expression.Lambda<Func<TModel, string>>(propertyAccess, paramExpr);

        if (showLabels)
            sb.AppendLine(helper.LabelFor(lambdaExpr).ToString());
        sb.AppendLine(helper.EditorFor(lambdaExpr).ToString());

        return MvcHtmlString.Create(sb.ToString());
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to use reflection to get to the value. You've specified a generic type constraint, so .NET knows the `TModel` has to be `IAddress`.

You should simply be able to do

```
var city = helper.ViewData.Model.City;
```

In fact, you should be able to do away with the generic method altogether - just use `HtmlHelper<IAddress>` as the parameter, and it should work just fine.

Also, you can use `helper.Label` etc. instead of `helper.LabelFor` - they work the same way but don't need an expression, just the name of the property.

Comment: Using the helper.ViewData.Model.City works nicely for getting the values of that property, but what I need is for the Attributes on those properties to be use. Such as the DisplayName for the Label and the validations on the Editor. I don't see right off how this would allow that?

Comment: @WebDevNewbie Doesn't that just work automatically when using `helper.Label`? In any case, look at `ModelMetadataProviders.Current.GetMetadataForType` - it gives you all of those attributes based on the type automatically, no need to mess with the attributes on your own.

Comment: helper.Label(helper.ViewData.Model.City) sets the label value to to the value of the City property, not the value of the attribute on the City property. helper.LabelFor does, but that requires an expression which would require TModel. I will experiment with the ModelMetadataProviders for a bit here and see where it goes :)

Comment: @WebDevNewbie Really? It shouldn't be doing that... what about `helper.DisplayName`?

Comment: @Luann - Yes, does the same thing for DisplayName as well. Just to be sure it wasn't something in my helper mucking it up, I added them directly to the view, same result.

Comment: Looks like going at it this way I will need to add each of the html validation attributes to the Html.Editor manually, which is doable, but tedious. I will probably start working on trying to get that pushed out, but if you have any other ideas in the meantime, I am open :)

Comment: I have a separate class taking a generic type that contains methods for generating various types of HtmlExtensions and returning the value as the String. Marking this as correct since it helped clean up my code a bit and got me pointed in the right direction. Will come back and update my question with an example of what I did. Thank you!